# Unable to start Hive with derby on Windows 10

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I am trying to configure Hive on top of Hadoop-2.7.3 in Windows 10. My Hadoop is running perfectly. But I'm facing the following error when I start the Hive on command line:

> Not a valid JAR:
>   E:\hadoop-2.7.3\hive\bin\org.apache.hive.beeline.cli.HiveCli

Whenever I type `hive` on the cmd after going to the bin directory of hive which is placed inside Hadoop home i.e $Hadoop_home/hive.

The error that I get is:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> File Not Found
>
> Not a valid JAR:
>
> E:/hadoop-2.7.3\hive\bin\org.apache.hive.beeline.cli.HiveCli

My `hive_home`, `hive_bin`, `hive_conf_dir` variables are set.
The PATH variable is also set to include `hive`.
`HIVE_HOME` is also set.

MY hive-site.xml is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
        <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
        <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.enable.impersonation</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
        <value>NONE</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
        <value>True</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

I also initialize the derby network server before running Hive.

Hope this explains the question. Please tell me if I need to add something else.

I would like to add that I checked the default bin folder of pig and it was empty so I ran the `pig` command from the pig-src extracted file and the error I got then was:

> 'E:/hadoop-2.7.3\bin\hadoop-config.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> '-Xmx1000M' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.